# SQL Server cumulative grouping

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has list of files and folders imported from a csv file. The table has as columns mainly `FullName` (path to the file or folder) and `FileExtension`.

I am able get a list of all folders and corresponding number of files in those folders using the below query

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(FullName, 0, LEN(FullName) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(FullName)) + 1) AS RootFolder, 
    COUNT(*) AS FileCount
FROM
    FileDump 
WHERE
    NULLIF(FileExtension, '') IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING(FullName, 0, LEN(FullName) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(FullName)) + 1)
ORDER BY
    FileCount DESC
```

However what I would like to get is if the folder has subfolders and those subfolders have files, then the filecount for any folder should also include all those files underneath

Sample data for FullName

```
C:\Folder1
C:\Folder1\File1.xlsx
C:\Folder1\File2.xlsx
C:\Folder1\Folder2
C:\Folder1\Folder2\file3.xlsx
```

Expected result

```
C:\Folder1  - 3
C:\Folder1\Folder2 - 1
```

Comment: doesn't your existing query gives you the required result ? If it is not, please highlight the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to start from the folders.
Which are those that don't have an extension.

Then left joins the files and group on the folders to count the files.

```
SELECT 
 [folder].FullName AS RootFolder, 
 COUNT([file].FullName) AS FileCount
FROM FileDump AS [folder]
LEFT JOIN FileDump AS [file] 
  ON NULLIF([file].FileExtension, '') IS NOT NULL 
 AND [file].FullName LIKE CONCAT([folder].FullName,'\%')
WHERE NULLIF([folder].FileExtension, '') IS NULL
GROUP BY [folder].FullName
ORDER BY RootFolder;
```

Result:

```
RootFolder          FileCount
------------------  ---------
C:\Folder1          3
C:\Folder1\Folder2  1
```